# What is the difference between boundary point and frontier point? Please explain with examples.

Tags: general-topology

What are actually boundary point and frontier point?
Some books say that a point a belonging to S is a boundary point of S if it's a frontier point of S.
Some books say, it isn't obvious that a belongs to S.
Which is correct?
Tell me if both of them are wrong.
Please explain.

Comment: Whatever each book says is correct within that book. That's how it works.

Comment: I think that in ordinary English one would assume that the frontier certainly belonged to the country, or whatever, whereas the boundary might not. So probably the definitions should reflect this.